# MVC error expecting scripts section on integer return value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a strange issue on the shopping cart on my site. I am getting this error:

> Error in: https://blah.com/ShoppingCart/GetAvailability
>   Error Message: Section not defined: "Scripts".
>   Stack Trace:    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSection(String name, Boolean required)
>      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSection(String name)

The problem is that the controller method that it cannot find a "Scripts" section for returns an integer, not a page. It is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public int GetAvailability(string sku)
{
    ECCDestinationConfig cfg = new ECCDestinationConfig();

    try
    {
        RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(cfg);
        ... Calculate the stock quantity from SAP
        return runningTotal;
    }
    catch
    {
        // make sure the destination is unregistered
        RfcDestinationManager.UnregisterDestinationConfiguration(cfg);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The controller method is called via ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ShoppingCart/GetAvailability",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'sku': '@Model.Product.SKU' }),
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        //Code to set a span to show a green check if over 0 and a red
        //exclamation if under.
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#@id').addClass("fg-crimson fa fa-exclamation");
    }
});
```

So, the method should only ever return an integer, but I am having users report problems and I am seeing the "scripts" not defined error message in the error logs. I am unable to reproduce this while debugging. I don't understand why the server is ever expecting a page here. The weird part is, if I reset the app pool for the site, the problem will go away temporarily. I am clearly not trapping some error somewhere, but I can't imagine what that might be.

Comment: Does the ajax page have a form and do you prevent the form's default submission?

Comment: @Jasen the ajax call actually comes from a partial view within a table. The partial shows a loading icon until it gets a result, at which point it displays a check mark or exclamation. there is usually more than one call per page, as it is per line item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error's likely cause is, I say likely cause because I have not seen your code, you have         @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) in the view, with required attribute set to true, @RenderSection("scripts", required: true). If it is set to true and you do not provide the javascript you will get the error. When you set it to false, then you are telling the razor engine please ignore me if I do not provide the scripts. So set it to false and you will be fine.

Comment: I am actually not passing the second argument at all, which I guess defaults to true. I will give this a shot.

Comment: As per my last sentence, please set it to false